# APDU: "Conditions of use not satisfied" (69 85) while calculate signature

Tags: certificate, smartcard, private-key, apdu

With a smart card Gemalto (IAS ECC), I would to calculate a signature by using private key stored on smart card. For this, I use APDU commands:

```
// Verify PIN
00 20 00 01 04 31 32 33 34
-> 90 00

// Create a context for security operation
00 22 41 B6 06 84 01 84 80 01 12
-> 90 00

// Set the hash of the document
00 2A 90 A0 14 HASH OF DOCUMENT
-> 69 85

// Calculating the signature
00 2A 9E 9A 80
-> 69 85
```

My problem is the following: the las two commands return the error code "69 85", meaning "Conditions of use not satisfied".

I have already tried several solutions, but I obtain always the same error. How to resolve it? What does this code can mean?

After some tests, I discovered something interesting. When I replace cla "00" by "10", smart card returns a different response:

```
// Create a context for security operation
00 22 41 B6 06 84 01 84 80 01 12

// Verify PIN
00 20 00 01 04 31 32 33 34

// Calculating the signature (I replace "00" by "10")
10 2A 9E 9A 23 30 21 30 09 06 05 2B 0E 03 02 1A 05 00 04 14 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 12 13 14 15
```

I don't know if it's the good solution because smart card returns "90 00". But, it would return the content of my signature!

Thank you for your help!

Best regards

Comment: Testing random things in the CLA bytes won't get you anywhere. You probably just indicated command chaining and the card is signaling it wants to receive the rest of the data (after which you will get the same error back, most probably).

Comment: did u find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting SW 6985 for

```
// Set the hash of the document
00 2A 90 A0 14 HASH OF DOCUMENT
-> 69 85
```

Since you have not set the correct context in current security environment.

Let me explain this below

First you performed VERIFY PIN command which was successful

```
// Verify PIN
00 20 00 01 04 31 32 33 34
-> 90 00
```

Then you performed MSE SET command,Where you set the security context.For this you have to understood how SE works(Please refer to section 3.5 fron IAS ECC v1.01).

At the time of personalisation, the Personaliser agent create SDO(Secure Data Object) inside the card.The reference to this SDO are mentioned in SE(Security Environment) in form of CRT(Control reference template).

```
// Create a context for security operation
00 22 41 B6 06 84 01 84 80 01 12
-> 90 00
```

Generally speaking, MSE SET command will always return SW 900 even if the SDO reference is wrong. Since it only return SW 6A80 when the template is wrong not when the reference is wrong.(The SDO reference is passed in tag 84)

After that you performed PSO HASH command

```
// Set the hash of the document
00 2A 90 A0 14 HASH OF DOCUMENT
-> 69 85
```

where the card return SW 6985(Condition of use not satisfied), This indicate the algorithm and SDO reference used for calculating Hash may  wrong. Which is probably happening since the SDO reference which was sent during the time of MSE SET command is not available

Detecting error coming from MSE SET could be tricky since it return SW 9000.
For these type of situation you have to check the personalisation file carefully and need to match the MSE SET command with regard to SDO reference and supported ALGOs.

It may be useful to put the default context (e.g., cryptographic algorithms or
security operations) into the current SE in order to have few exchanges of MSE set commands.